# queries regarding neo4j HA setup

Tags: neo4j

Hi I am new to HA concepts and Neo4j HA. I have gone through the Neo4j Docs but i still have a couple of questions that come to my mind.

1. When using a php script to connect to Neo4j database via REST what ip should i use for the cluster. Is there a common ip for the cluster?

I ask this because if the master fails a new neo4j instance becomes the master. how should my script connect to the new master. Should i use third party software for pointing to the new master. can that happen automatically with neo4j through a common cluster ip. pardon me if my concepts are weak, just need some guidance.

2. How can i direct all reads and writes to the master only and use the slaves only for replication. Or is this the default setting. I see multiple read & multiple write scenarios so i am getting confused.
3. Is there any doc/material that explains further on setting up an Arbiter Instance or should i just configure 3 node Neo4j HA as explained in http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html and run the below command for one of the instance -

   `neo4j_home$ ./bin/neo4j-arbiter start`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the community of Neo4j Users ;)

First I recommend you to look on [neo4j-php-client](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client), because it support Neo4j HA cluster and it could solve your question and problems. Instead of finding your own solutions.

1. Best practice is to use some kind of load balancing front of the Neo4j HA Cluster. Here is the great article about it: http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2015/08/neo4j-and-haproxy-some-best-practices-and-tricks/
2. You can do that on load balancer level based on HTTP methods (GET redirect to slaves; POST, PUT, DELETE redirect to master). But there is a problem with Cypher endpoint, because it uses only POST method. You can use additional HTTP header to distinguish between read and write request, but that logic must be in your application.
3. For start it's good enough to start with official documentation.

Resources

- [Neo4j HA cluster configuration (example)](https://github.com/MicTech/neo4j-ha-configuration)
- [Neo4j cluster and firewalls](http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2015/09/neo4j-cluster-and-firewalls/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! 1) just to see if i understood this right - a load balancer is mandate for automated failover? & for point 3) what i meant was if I just run `neo4j-arbiter start` on one of the HA instances would it behave like an arbitrator only without any transaction being logged on to the instance.

Comment: Load balancer is not mandatory but highly recommended. Neo4j-arbiter start is different service it's not real Neo4j server.

Comment: Thanks again! Do you have any links/docs/materials that further talk about setting up Neo4j-arbiter as a part of the cluster.

Comment: Or for a two node setup for that matter. Thanks

Comment: For two node setup you don't need arbiter.

Comment: What i meant was 2 nodes - 1 node with 1 db instance and 1  node with 1 db instance + 1 arbiter instance. The doc says - _a scenario where you have a cluster of 2 Neo4j database instances and an additional arbiter instance and still enjoy tolerance of a single failure of either of the 3 instances._ ( http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/arbiter-instances.html ). Is there another alternative method to have a two node setup? I just need one additional realtime copy of the database. Let me post a new question to describe my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As my friend MicTech mentioned, generally we use HAProxy as load balancer on top of Neo4j.

With the php client mentioned, you have a great configuration mechanism that allows to :

1. When using HA Proxy, define your read/write queries so it will automatically add a header to the http request. The header is configurable too.
2. When not using HAProxy, you can in the client setup, define all your neo4j instances and activate the High-Availibility extension (works only with cache enabled). So when the master is down, the client will automatically try to detect the new elected master and rewrite the connections configuration in the cache for further requests.

I tried to make the README as good as possible, please read it and open issues on the repository if there are things that are missing.

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client

Comment: Thanks & Great API. Just went through the doc. It says _Automatically, write queries will be executed against the master connection, while read queries against slave connections._ I also see there a read and write modes. Is there a way to direct all read and writes to the master itself? Is there provision to add Arbiter as well, (I know there won't be read and write on the arbiter but would this work in that setup)? Thanks for the same!

Comment: If you don't use the specific read and writes methods, these are assumed as write so directed to master. Also you can pass the connection alias to each method of the client to direct to the connection you want. Why would it not work with an arbiter. Also I think you will have lot of more things to think about than to worry about the arbiter.

Comment: Sure. Thanks again for the answer !